# Preg_match to ignore new lines or tabs

Tags: php, web-scraping, preg-match

My html output source is something like this

```
<td><span class="bookdetailtitle">ISBN</span></td>
                            <td>:</td>
                            <td>9788172338299</td>
```

I need only 9788172338299 to be printed. If the above code is in same line, it prints properly. But since there are new lines and tabs, I'm not getting the output. I tried replacing /i with /s, but not working. I want preg_match to match the string regardless of new lines or tabs and print the desired output.

Here is my code:

```
$page2='<td><span class="bookdetailtitle">ISBN</span></td>
                            <td>:</td>
                            <td>9788172338299</td>';

preg_match('/<td><span class="bookdetailtitle">ISBN<\/span><\/td><td>:<\/td><td>(.*)<\/td>/s', $page2, $keywords);
echo $keywords_out = $keywords[1];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need just number, something like this?

```
$page2='<td><span class="bookdetailtitle">ISBN</span></td>
                            <td>:</td>
                            <td>9788172338299</td>';

preg_match('/<td>+[0-9]+<\/td>/', $page2, $keywords);
print_r($keywords);
```

**http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/43j-t8b**

P.S. many will say - don't use regex for parsing html. I agree. :)

I would do something like this:

```
$page=explode('<td>',$page2);
print_r($page[3]);
```

**http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/buf-95c**

Edit: to get rid of last td -> `print_r(strip_tags($page[3]));`

Comment: I might have text also... What to do in that scenario?

Comment: Ok, you need content of LAST <td> (can be anything)?